# Opening the code file which in the HTML file and go to the given line number

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I have a XSl file which reads an XML file and create an HTML file.

In the HTML file there are some links which refer to some files and a number line of the file(all file are codes). I would like to know that how can I write a code in Javascript so that by clicking in the link opens the file in Notepad++ and shows the line which is referred by the number.

For example let's I have the following link:

```
C:\test\test.py (42)
```

Then by clicking in the link I would like to ope the above file and go to the line number 42.

Comment: here's the [notepad++ documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches) that I found using [this](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=notepad%2B%2B+command+line+options) - the `-n` *linenumber* option is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jaromanda. Here is the answer:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" C:\test\test.py -n42
```